# How to remove cursor from a Map (Bukkit)

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm currently developing a plugin which only renders an image to a map like this:

```
public class MapRendererTest extends MapRenderer {

    private Image image;

    public MapRendererTest(File file) {
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(MapView mapView, MapCanvas mapCanvas, Player player) {
        mapCanvas.drawImage(0, 0, image);
    }
}
```

everything works fine, but there is this little thing in the red circle that I want to remove but I don't know how.

[image: T]

**Things I already tried**

- Setting an emtpy `MapCursorCollection`
- `MapView.setWorld` to a world where no-one is playing.
- Creating `MapCursorCollection` with a invisible cursor

It would be amazing if someone could help me with that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the cursor, you have to remove all the other map renderers or at least the `CraftMapRanderer`.

In order to do this, you have to do the following:

```
@EventHandler
public void onMapInitialized(MapInitializeEvent e) {
    e.getMap().removeRenderer(e.getMap().getRenderers().get(0));
    e.getMap().addRenderer(new MapRendererTest(new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder() + "/image.png")));
}
```

This only works of course if there is no other custom map renderer assigned to this map, so the only registered is the `CraftMapRenderer`.

If you have multiple `MapRenderers` you could loop through the list and remove them.